# PHP isset function won't work

Tags: php, forms, function, mysqli, isset

The function is not triggered does anyone know how to make it work

```
if ($logged_in_bool == "true") {
    echo "<form action='page-settings.php?name=".$name."' method='POST'>
        <input type='button' name='delete_page' value='Delete Page'>
        </form>
";
} else {


}

$clicked_delete = @$_POST['delete_page'];

if (isset($clicked_delete)) {
    delete_page();
} else {
}

function delete_page() {
    echo "Page deleted";
}


?>
```

The function is not triggered does anyone know how to make it work

Comment: What happens if the `@` is removed?

Comment: Why not simply `if (isset($_POST['delete_page']))`?

Comment: The IF will only work after you submit the page. Plus is you get an error FIX IT, dont hide it with `@` error supression

Comment: Also if `$logged_in_bool` is in fact a Boolean this should be `if ($logged_in_bool) {`

Comment: `if ($logged_in_bool == "true")` you checking for boolean or a string here? Two different animals here. and no idea how this is getting populated `?name`.

Comment: Don't suppress errors. Deal with them properly.

Answer (score 0):

In line 3 `type=button` should be replaced by `type=submit` because `type=button` doesn't submit the form unless you fiddle with some JavaScript to do that, when the POST form isn't submitted there is nothing in the $_POST variable, therefore $_POST['delete_page] is not set. See modified code down below:

```
// $name is probably the name of the page to be deleted, not mentioned in the question
$name = 'example';
// $logged_in_bool comes from somewhere else not mentioned in this problem
$logged_in_bool = true;
if ($logged_in_bool) 
{
    echo "<form action='page-settings.php?name=" . $name . "' method='POST'>
              <!-- Input type changed from button to submit -->
              <input type='submit' name='delete_page' value='Delete Page'>
          </form>";
}
// If the $_POST['delete_age'] from the form is available, delete the page
if (isset($_POST['delete_page'])) {
    delete_page();
} else { }

function delete_page() {
    echo "Page deleted";
}
```

Comment: Hope you dont mind the edit with some additional description

Comment: There is quite a bit more you should do here, look at all the other comments

Answer (score 0):

why you not use type='submit' ? So, how if you try to change type button into type submit, like this:

```
<input type='button' name='delete_page' value='Delete Page'>
```

Change to:

```
<input type='submit' name='delete_page' value='Delete Page'>
```

Answer (score 0):

As my pre poster already told you what to do, i wanna tell you that the reason why the isset statement is not working is that the variable $clicked_delete IS actually set, since you declare it and give it the value of  $_POST['delete_page']. So you either use

```
$clicked_deleted = (isset($_POST['deleted_page'])) ? true : false;

if ($clicked_deleted) { /* ... */ }
```

or you could use the empty function (i recommend the first solution)

```
if (!empty($_POST['deleted_page'])) { /* ... */ }
```

Comment: No, the `@` is not needed with `empty`.  `No warning is generated if the variable does not exist. That means empty() is essentially the concise equivalent to !isset($var) || $var == false.`.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying, i wasnt sure anymore since i don´t use the empty function a lot. Edited my post.